# Are WinJS/Metro Apps single threaded?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, windows-8, windows-runtime, winjs

I read in Windows 8 development tutorial that Metro apps written using HTML/JavaScript runs on single thread. If so, how it executes asynchronous functions in WinRT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the JavaScript engine is indeed single-threaded. Calls to the API are all native code though and as such can - and mostly do - open separate threads.

See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh781217.aspx) for a thorough explanation of the underlying mechanics as well as some recommendations on how to deal with this in your code.
The WinJS Promise internally also uses `setImmediate` to allow the rendering and message loop to take over between multiple JavaScript functions and - as an important side-effect - shorten the callstack.

Answer (score 2):

It's a multi part answer.

Traditionally - yes it is single threaded. Async is done behind the scenes with timers.
However with the advent of web workers, you can run background processing on multiple threads (or use a Windows Runtime component that does threading and relies on .NET for the threading here).

Web Workers are supported in Windows Store HTMl/JS applications so yes, you can have more than one thread.

[Web Workers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673568%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)